# What does this.constructor.prototype.constructor.apply mean in js

Tags: javascript

I was reading [this](http://flippinawesome.org/2013/06/03/javascript-inheritance-how-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-with-prototypes/) article, and I can't figure out what the below line does. Even if I remove this line, I can't see any difference.

`this.constructor.prototype.constructor.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));`

Could someone explain me why `this.constructor.prototype.constructor` is necessary, wouldn't `this.constructor` return the same value?

Comment: Please revise the title so that future visitors with the same question can find it. The current title is too vague.

Comment: Would you like to advise? I don't feel I am knowledgable enough in this area of JS to put something meaningful

Comment: That's much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, what it's trying to do is call the constructor function for the object that is the current object's prototype.

Breaking it down:

- `this` - The current object
- `this.constructor` - The `constructor` property on the current object, which is almost certainly (but not necessarily!) inherited from its prototype. And so it's probably (but not necessarily) the function that created the object.
- `this.constructor.prototype` - The object assigned to that function's `prototype` property. (The object that will be assigned as the underlying prototype of objects created if you call that function via `new`.)
- `this.constructor.prototype.constructor` - The function that created *that* object.

...and then we call `apply` on it to set `this` within the call to the current `this`, and use `Array.prototype.slice` to make a copy of the current arguments as a true array. (That last part is unnecessary, [`apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) accepts anything that's *array-like*, it doesn't require true arrays. So the code could just use `arguments` directly.)

Comment: Side note: If you're interested in building inheritance hierarchies with JavaScript's prototypical inheritance, [my `Lineage` script](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) simplifies things markedly (in my view).

Comment: Basically, `this.constructor.prototype` is just `this.__proto__` except that it works in Opera? :-)

Comment: Great, will take a look at that, thanks. The problem I am currently having is it seems via the article's code, Widget is called twice, once within the subclass, and once to override the SubWidgets prototype. Would'nt it be enough to just do it once directly on the SubWidget's prototype? Why is it necessary to do it within the subclasses body?

Comment: @JanDvorak: *Provided* nothing has assigned something to the function's `prototype` property in the meantime, yeah. (There's also ES5's `Object.getPrototypeOf`.)